# Exit of Java process with exit code -805306369 (0xCFFFFFFF)

Tags: java

We're developing a Java application, running on OpenJDK 1.8.0.40 (32-bit) on Windows 10 (64-bit). Sometimes we get an unexpected exit of the Java process with exit code -805306369, which is hex 0xCFFFFFFF. We don't have any clue on what's causing this issue, as there is no stack trace whatsoever.

Anybody recognize this error? Any clue on what the exit code means?

Comment: Are there any third-party libraries u use? if not, the process is probably terminated by the VM itself due to some internal issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a breakpoint at java.lang.Runtime#exit() to check if someone calls System.exit() or Runtime.exit() explicitly.

In addition, there is what could be the cause: https://community.bistudio.com/wiki/Arma_3_Unusual_process_exit#0xCFFFFFFF_-_APPLICATION_HUNG
The OS could terminate the process with the exit code APPLICATION_HUNG

Comment: Good suggestion. The challenge is that the problem only occurs once every few weeks on one of the many systems under test.

Comment: Look at the update of the answer. This could be what you are looking for